# Maven Multi-module dependency package does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, multi-module

I've got a multi module project

I want to use the methods (services, entities) of the web module in the batch module.
I am using it by adding the dependency of the web module.

There is no problem when starting in IDE (IntelliJ), but when I build it for distribution,
it says that there is no web module package.

The parent POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project .....>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>web-module</module>
        <module>batch-module</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>parent-module</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>
            <name>Aspose Java API</name>
            <url>https://releases.aspose.com/java/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        ......
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The web module POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project .....`your text`>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <artifactId>web-module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Querydsl-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The batch module POM.xml:

```
<project .....>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <artifactId>batch-module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-module</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If I try to perform a maven clean install on the parent project, I get the following result:

```
[INFO] -----------------------< com.xyz:sbatch-module >------------------------
[INFO] Building batch-module 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                              [3/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
C:......\InterviewEndJobConfiguration.java:3: error: package xxxx does not exist
import com.xyz.xxxxx.model.TZoomSchedule;
......
[INFO] --- apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process (default) @ batch-module ---
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for parent-module 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parent-module ............................................ SUCCESS [  1.740 s]
[INFO] web-module    ............................................ SUCCESS [ 18.912 s]
[INFO] batch-module  ............................................ FAILURE [  3.071 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  23.974 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-10-03T14:07:54+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project batch-module: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
```

I've been breaking my head on this issue for several days now, but I don't have a clue why this isn't working.

Comment: You cannot use a Spring Boot jar (application) as a dependency for another. If both applications need to share classes, create a third module which doesn't have the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` but produces just a regular jar file. As your `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is defined in your parent, you will need to move that down to both the web and batch modules.

Comment: I moved spring-boot-maven-plugin to web and batch, but the error still occurs.

Comment: Read, please read. You need **If both applications need to share classes, create a third module which doesn't have the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` but produces just a regular jar**

Comment: Sorry for the hasty comment. I solved the problem thanks to your advice. thank you so so much